How to Enable Auto-Complete for Custom Path Functions in PhpStorm?
How can I enable auto-complete in PhpStorm for a function that takes a string input, where the string represents a file path?
For example, with JavaScript, I define a function like this:
function asset(path: string) {
    return `/public/static/${path}`;
};

The goal is to have the path values auto-completed as I type. How can this be achieved?
For instance, in Laravel, we have auto-completion like this:

Can we achieve the same for custom functions?

For PHP, you could use #[Language] PHP attribute on that parameter (see https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-attributes?tab=readme-ov-file#language) .. but that still does not seem to support file-reference (the one that tells that the file path is expected here: WI-56996 & WI-20028).

I want to add the asset function in JavaScript

For other languages (e.g. JavaScript) -- I'm not sure at all. In theory could use the general Language Injections functionality (IDE level kind of settings), but the File Reference language still does not seem to be in the list... P.S. Could try workaround with some HTML as an intermediate language, but not sure if this will work...

"I want to add the asset function in JavaScript" Then why tagging php and laravel?

Yap, I think i have to make a plugin for PHP Storm for doing that.

I used PHP and Laravel for telling that these are example of what i want to do

Refer to this thread: Force autocomplete suggestions for file paths
It seems that what you are asking for is not a standard feature of PHPStorm. The answer of the given thread also discusses a manual solution, but that only lasts until the file or project is closed.

So how do plugins like Laravel Idea provide auto-complete for Laravel functions? There must be a way to add custom auto-complete suggestions for specific functions we have in mind.

You can make such an injection by utilizing some intermediate language (where the file reference works)... but it will have some limitations and may not work exactly as you want:

The function name better be unique
the path will be relative to the folders marked as "Resource Root" (or the current folder / project root if none like that found).

Worth checking it out anyway.

Here is what can be achieved right now:

Settings/Preferences | Editor | Language Injections
Make a new rule of Generic Js kind
Inject HTML language with an additional Prefix and Suffix, This way the IDE would think that we are in that HTML attribute where injection already works (you can try another TAG/attribute that may work better, here I have used <a> and href).
The pattern to use: + jsArgument("assetMe", 0):

assetMe is the function name where to inject it
0 in the parameter number (first one in this case)



This how it looks and works (tested in a plain JavaScript file):

Sample test code:
function assetMe(path: string) {
    return `/public/static/${path}`;
}

assetMe('');

This is how it works here in my simple test (lists files from the same folder as I do not have any folders marked as Resource Root):

